# Firebase Auth gives ViewPostIme pointer 1 While running on a physical device but work on Android Emulator ( Firebase works only on emulator )

Tags: java, android, firebase

**UPDATE:** Any project that uses firebase is working only on emulator, I tried.
*THE APP WORKS AS INTENDED ONLY IN THE EMULATOR*

When I test the app on a physical device, I get the following.
[LogCat output screenshot][1]

This is the LogCat output evertime I click my login button

Here is my **MainActivity.java** file

```
package com.abg.logintest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextInputEditText email,pass;
    String emailText,password;
    Button login;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.pass);

        login = findViewById(R.id.button);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }
    private void loginUser(String email, String password){
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("TAG", "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("TAG", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
        if(currentUser!=null)
        Log.d("login",currentUser.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        emailText = email.getText().toString();
        password = pass.getText().toString();
        loginUser(emailText,password);
    }
}
```

Here is the **Main Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="email"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.265">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have included all dependencies that are required to run firebase

[My Module level dependencies :APP][2]

[Permissions I have mentioned in my Manifest file][3]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8XY8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIm6a.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kBVy.png

Answer (score 0):

So after rummaging through the whole code I found out
["new OnCompleteListener()" was grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MebD2.png) and the IDE suggested "Anonymous new OnCompleteListener() can be replaced with lambda",
 So I replaced it with lambda 
And surprisingly enough the app now works on actual device as well.

[BEFORE THE LAMBDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MebD2.png)

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {....
```

[AFTER THE LAMBDA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dvBm.png)

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {...
```

Although I am still confused on why in one project the "new onCompleteListener..." was not greyed out and worked fine but in another project it needed to be replaced with a lambda function.

and now the question is why does the app works fine on the emulator regardless of the lambda functions presence and it needed lambda to work on an actual device.